# Nesting resources within a singular resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing

Given the following routes:

```
resource :public_profile do
  resources :posts
end

resource :private_profile do
  resources :posts
end
```

How can I, in the `PostsController`, determine which singular resource I am nested within?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you could do this is by creating 2 more controllers that extend some main `PostsController`, and use

```
resource :public_profile do
  resources :posts, controller: "PublicPostsController"
end

resource :private_profile do
  resources :posts, controller: "PrivatePostsController"
end
```

You could even do this in a variety of ways. For example, maybe it makes sense to have

```
class ProfileController < ApplicationController; end
class PostsController < ApplicationController; end

class Private::ProfileController < ProfileController; end
class Private::PostsController < PostsController; end

class Public::ProfileController < ProfileController; end
class Public::PostsController < PostsController; end
```

with routing

```
resource :public_profile, controller: "Public::ProfileController" do
  resources :posts, controller: "Public::PostsController"
end

resource :private_profile, controller: "Private::ProfileController" do
  resources :posts, controller: "Private::PostsController"
end
```

Regardless of how you set this up, you can easily 'know'  what resource you're nested within because you'll actually be running within a separate controller specific to that nesting and can thus have a perfect place for logic specific to that nesting. For general logic, you'd put that into the parent `PostsController`.

---

Another way you could do this is by adding a `before_filter` to `PostsController` like

```
before_filter :check_nesting

private
  def check_nesting
    @is_public_profile = params.include?(:public)
  end
```

and have routing like

```
resource :public_profile, public: true do
  resources :posts, controller: "PublicPostsController"
end

resource :private_profile, private: true do
  resources :posts, controller: "PrivatePostsController"
end
```

I don't care for this approach though.

Comment: I ended up getting a working version based on your last answer (using params in the routes) but eventually ditched the concept entirely and went with a more traditional `resources`-based approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can route them to different controllers ( by specifying it in the routes) , that are extended from the same "base" controller PostsController. In the extended controllers you 
identify them:

EX:

```
resource :public_profile do
  resources :posts, :controller => "public_profile_posts_controller"
end

resource :private_profile do
  resources :posts, :controller => "private_profile_posts_controller"
end
```

and the Controllers

```
class PublicProfilePostsController < PostsController
 before_filter :identify_controller

 def identify_controller
  @nested_resource_of = :public_profile
 end
end

class PrivateProfilePostsController < PostsController
 before_filter :identify_controller

 def identify_controller
  @nested_resource_of = :private_profile
 end
end
```

and then you have access to the variable

> `@nested_resource_of`

in the PostsController actions